# how do I duplicate a regular expression

Tags: regex, emacs

I want to search for all the phrases that are in quotes and then duplicate them.

In Emacs, my search looks like this:

`M-x replace-regexp <RETURN> "*" <RETURN> $& $& <RETURN>`

But it doesn't work...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"*"` doesn't match a quote-delimited string; it matches any (nonzero) number of quotation marks in a row.

In regular expressions, `*` is a modifier, not the wildcard that it is in filename patterns. It means "match 0 or more of the previous pattern", so `"*"` is "0 or more quotation marks, followed by a quotation mark" - that is, any number of quotation marks in a row.

The usual regular expression for "anything" is `.*` which matches 0 or more of "any character" (`.`).  But that would include quotation marks; `".*"` would match everything from the first quotation mark to the last as one big string.  What you want is `"[^"]*"`, which matches a quotation mark, followed by any number of non-quotation marks, followed by another quotation mark.

Also, the matched pattern is `\&`, not `$&`. This might work better:

```
M-x replace-regexp <RETURN> "[^"]*" <RETURN> \& \& <RETURN>
```

Comment: You could also use `".*?"`. When following a `*`, `+`, or `?` modifier, a question mark makes that preceding modifier *non-greedy*, so `.*?` matches as *few* of "any character" as possible to satisfy the pattern. See `C-h i g` `(elisp) Regexp Special` `RET`

Comment: @mark-reed thank you so much for the reply. When I try your method in Aquamacs, I get `invalid use of '\' in replacement text`. Any thoughts? Thanks again.

Comment: @PeterSalazar Sorry, no. It works fine for me in Aquamacs here: I hit option-x, type `replace-regexp`, hit the return key, type `"[^"]*"`, hit the return key, type `\&`, press space, type `\&` again, hit the return key, and get a message `Replaced 0 occurrences`.